# YouTube Analytics API php Samples

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics

I want to make this YouTube Analytics Request with the PHP Client Libary

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports  
?ids=channel==CHANNELID
&start-date=STARTDATE
&end-date=ENDDATE 
&metrics=views,  
estimatedMinutesWatched,  
averageViewDuration,  
comments,  
favoritesAdded,  
favoritesRemoved,  
likes,  
dislikes,  
shares,  
subscribersGained,  
subscribersLost  
&dimensions=7DayTotals 
&fields=rows  
&sort=day
```

Is this possible?
Are there any PHP code Samples on how the get a YouTube Analytics Report from the API?
Couldn't find one on the Google Developers page .(https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/code_samples/)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add metrics in the following way rather than calling each metric one by one.

```
$metrics = 'views,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration,comments,favoritesAdded,favoritesRemoved,likes,dislikes,shares,subscribersGained,subscribersLost';
```

Your result will be in the from as depicted in the documentation.
Example:

```
$optparams = array(
    'dimensions' => '7DayTotals',
    'sort' => 'day',
);

$metrics = 'views,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration,comments,favoritesAdded,favoritesRemoved,likes,dislikes,shares,subscribersGained,subscribersLost';

$api_response = $metrics;
$api = $analytics->reports->query($id, $start_date, $end_date, $metric, $optparams);

if (isset($api['rows'])) {
    //Get values in form of multidimensional arrays. 
}
```

Comment: How would I add this parameter: include-historical-channel-data=true as per https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reference/reports/query#include-historical-channel-data ?

Comment: @pdolinaj I believe you could just add it to the `$optparams` like this
`$optparams = [
    'dimensions' => '7DayTotals',
    'sort' => 'day',
    'include-historical-channel-data' => TRUE,
];
`

Comment: To use `$analytics` do this:
`composer require google/apiclient:^2.11;`
`$analytics = new Google\Service\YouTubeAnalytics($client);`

Answer (score 7):

After authorizing and/or refreshing tokens, in PHP:

```
$analytics = new Google_YouTubeAnalyticsService($client);
// $client is your Google_Client object

// here we set some params
$id = 'channel==CHANNELID'
$start_date = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
$end_date = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
$optparams = array(
    'dimensions' => '7DayTotals',
    'sort' => 'day',
);

$metrics = array(
    'views',
    'estimatedMinutesWatched',
    'averageViewDuration',
    'comments',
    'favoritesAdded',
    'favoritesRemoved',
    'likes',
    'dislikes',
    'shares',
    'subscribersGained',
    'subscribersLost'
);

$api_response = $metrics;

// You can only get one metric at a time, so we loop
foreach ($metrics as $metric)
{
    $api = $analytics->reports->query($id, $start_date, $end_date, $metric, $optparams);
    if (isset($api['rows'])) $api_response[$metric] = $api['rows'][0][0];
}
```

---

EDIT: made it so that, to get results, you can echo $api_response['metric you want'].

Answer (score 0):

This collects day-by-day analytics over the last 30 days and then inserts it into a database.
Here's the code:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/home/google-api-php-client/src');

require_once('Google/autoload.php');

require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner'));
$client->setDeveloperKey($key);

$analytics = new Google_Service_YouTubeAnalytics($client);

$ids = 'channel==' . $channel_url . '';
$end_date = date("Y-m-d"); 
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-30 days"));
$optparams = array(
'dimensions' => 'day',
);

$metric = 'views';

try{

$api = $analytics->reports->query($ids, $start_date, $end_date, $metric, $optparams);

foreach ($api->rows as $r) {
    $date = $r[0];
    $views = $r[1];

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO test (date,views,channel_url) VALUES (:date,:views,:channel_url)");
$stmt->execute([':date' => $date, ':views' => $views, ':channel_url' => $channel_url]);
}
}catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    echo sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
    htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
}
```